# Adding columns dynamically to column list

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

i've built an correct working query with the query builder.

But now, there is a condition, where a method (that is responsible to dynamically ad some tables to the query) must add a columns to the query.

i've tried the following (it's much more complex, but its almost the same):

```
$querybuilder->select('EntityA.Property')
             ->from ('EntityA');

// here is happening some awesome stuff... ;-)
// Now i have to add the Table, and The column

$querybuilder->innerJoin('EntityB'); // this is working
$querybuilder->add('select', 'EntityB.Property'); // overwrites my columnlist
// $querybuilder->select('EntityB.Property'); // also overwrites my columnlist
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you not just assemble the select-clause seperately like this:

```
$fields = array();

$fields[] = "EntityA.Property"

// code here, and finally, you decide you need EntityB
$fields[] = "EntityB.Property"
$querybuilder->innerJoin('EntityB');

// done with building the query, assign select
$querybuilder->select($fields);
```

Comment: hm, it's more simple, ->select() can handle arrays ;-), but it would be nice to add it by a method, so i don't have to pass a new parameter. but thanks, it will work